# Change IP address of a Virtual Machine running linux ubuntu on windows 8?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I currently have created two virtual machines in VirtualBox both running linux Ubuntu 14.04, and now want to have them have different IP addresses. (By default, they have the same IP address.) However, when I go to the Network settings of a virtual machine, and try to use the "Bridged Adapter" instead of the "NAT" network, the Bridged Adapter simply offers "Not Selected", and no other network choice.

Thus, does anyone know how I can change the IP address of one of my virtual machines in another manner?

Comment: well you can use manual IP settings, for further reference you can check out this post
[How to assign different IP address to virtual machines in VirtualBox](https://dreamtodeff.com/how-to-assign-different-ip-address-to-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting a static IP like others suggested, I simply enabled "Bridged Adapter Mode" under "Network Connections", and then this made it such that each new virtual machine I made automatically had a new IP address.

If you click "Bridged Adapter Mode" and it doesn't have any choices (i.e.the only option is "Not Selected"), then you can simply go to "Network Connections" on your host machine, right-click on the network, click "properties", then "Install", then "Service", then "Add", then Install "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver". After doing so (and restarting my computer), it started giving me different IP addresses for each new virtual machine.

Comment: The Bridged Adapter Mode gaves me a BSOD with Windows 10. So I tried to instal the bridged network.  After clicking Add, choose Oracle Corporation > VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver, I restart my PC but I kept getting BSOD... So my solution was to use the NAT Network.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Virtual box also for testing. From windows 95 to 7 and Linux ;).

I have used the NAT mode and then assign an static ip and always this has been working in any OS. This will work inside the same ip range from the LAN.

Also please refer to this part of the documentation I guess this is a better way and the one required for yourself

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox is acting as a DHCP server for these virtual machines. You can either define static IP addresses for these machines, or simply set the IP address manually on each machine.  If you don't know how to set a static IP address on your Linux system you need to learn how to do this, so I would suggest you go with the second option.

There are detailed instructions on the Ubuntu site for setting a static IP address.  It is not difficult, but you need to know a few things before you do it and the instructions are much more detailed than what I could write here.  The instructions for configuring your network settings start on page 33 of official Ubuntu Server Guide.

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf