# Make virtualbox get a different IP address than my laptop

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, cluster, hadoop

I am trying to setup a 2-node Hadoop cluster (following this [guide](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/install-a-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/)), where the master is going to be my Ubuntu laptop and the slave a virtualbox running ubuntu.

I also read about [networking in virtualbox](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1), but I still have issues.

However, both have the same IP address and I now, in the master node, I have this `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   gsamaras
127.0.1.1   master
127.0.1.1   slave-1
```

This seems messed-up to me, thus I would like to give virtualbox's Ubuntu another IP. I did check this question [Change IP address of a Virtual Machine running linux ubuntu on windows 8?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146656/change-ip-address-of-a-virtual-machine-running-linux-ubuntu-on-windows-8), but what the answer proposed is not found in the *virtualbox*. What I have selected there is:

*Devices -> Network -> Bridged Adapter (name wlan0)*

with the default to be *NAT*. However the `/etc/hosts` file there has the same IP. I also did that for a new Ubuntu I created in virtualbox, before doing the Installation process of Ubuntu, but its `/etc/hosts`, is the same as the other Ubuntu in virtualbox, i.e.:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   gsamaras-VirtualBox
127.0.1.1   master
127.0.1.1   slave-1
```

**How to make the virtualbox's Ubuntu and my Ubuntu to have different IPs?**

---

EDIT:

On master node (i.e. my laptop)

```
hadoopuser@gsamaras:/home$ /sbin/ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:40:f2:d8:76:ca  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:38796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6705515 (6.7 MB)  TX bytes:6705515 (6.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:ca:bd:cf:22  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::208:caff:febd:cf22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:654899 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:442294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:746284872 (746.2 MB)  TX bytes:121215609 (121.2 MB)
```

and on the slave node (i.e. the virtualbox):

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-VirtualBox:~$ /sbin/ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a3:40:f1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea3:40f1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4748 (4.7 KB)  TX bytes:10743 (10.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12500 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:12500 (12.5 KB)
```

---

EDIT_1:

From the master node I did (while the virtualbox's network is set to Bridged Adapter with the name wlan0):

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ssh 192.168.1.5
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.5 port 22: No route to host
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ssh 192.168.1.2
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 78:21:77:e8:aa:c5:c5:41:8f:32:56:f7:c6:37:fc:a2.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ping 192.168.1.5
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
...
```

Comment: If you run `ifconfig -a` on the two systems, do you see any addresses other than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I was thinking to add that info, question updated! Do you have any suggestion(s)? :)

Comment: Do you have connectivity if you use those 192.168.1 addresses? Does the DHCP server handing out those addresses have a way to make them permanent?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick should I do an ssh? I mean how to check for connectivity? I am not sure how to determine this too. :/

Comment: You can try ssh, assuming you have an ssh server running on each system. If not, try ping.

Comment: I updated with the results @MarkPlotnick, I would say no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using bridged networking and your host and guest already have different IP addresses, **192.168.1.2** for the host (what you call master node) and **192.168.1.5** for the guest (slave node).

Don't be confused by addresses in the **127.x.x.x** network. These are loopback addresses and they never leave the TCP/IP stack, i.e. two different machines (whether real or virtual) cannot communicate together through them.

Comment: So everything is OK? I doubt it, since when I try to ssh from the host to guest, it fails.

Comment: Well, assuming the guest eth0 is configured to use DHCP, it got its IP from your wifi router. Did you try ping in either directions?

Comment: and are you sure sshd is enabled on the guest?

Comment: No, but your answer gave me ideas, I will work on that direction and post a new question if needed.

Comment: Ok, I'm somewhat perplexed after seeing in your updated question that ping actually fails...

Comment: Follow-up question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257262/host-cant-ssh-guest-but-guest-can.
I think it has to do with the Device->Network->Name option, where wlan0 and eth0 are the options and I might have played around. Which one should I use? the first gives me an IP addr., but the second doesn't. Also how do I check if `sshd` is enabled on the guest? `which` doesn't return anything, but it does for `ssh`. Same for `whereis`.

Comment: You should use wlan0 (assuming you are connected to a router through wireless interface), eth0 is the RJ45. To check sshd, run `ssh localhost` on the guest.

Comment: It refuses, I am updating the new question with this info, thanks!