# host can't ssh guest, but guest can

Tags: ssh, networking, virtualbox, ip, cluster

This is a follow-up question from: [Make virtualbox get a different IP address than my laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257218/make-virtualbox-get-a-different-ip-address-than-my-laptop). I ended up with these `/etc/hosts` files on both my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 (the host) and my virtualbox running Ubuntu 14.04 (the guest):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   gsamaras  // gsamaras-VirtualBox
192.168.1.2 master    // the host
192.168.1.9 slave-1   // the guest
```

I obtained the IPs with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x). When I set the virtualbox to eth0, this won't return anything and the network seems to be disconnected, so in the virtualbox, I have this setting:

> Devices -> Network -> Bridged Adapter (name wlan0)

I can ssh from guest to host with `ssh master`, but when on master, I am getting:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ssh slave-1
ssh: connect to host slave-1 port 22: Connection refused
```

Also notice that, when on guest, I am getting:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-VirtualBox:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

How to fix it?

---

EDIT:

From *guest*:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-VirtualBox:~$ netstat -an | grep -w LISTEN | grep -w 22
gsamaras@gsamaras-VirtualBox:~$
```

From *master*:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ping slave-1
PING slave-1 (192.168.1.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from slave-1 (192.168.1.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.360 ms
```

Comment: Are you sure the message is `connect to host slave-1 port 22` and not `connect to host localhost port 22` in your last test?

Comment: Good catch @jlliagre, I am posting from the master and the copy paster from the guest is hard. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way to check the ssh service is up and running locally on the guest:

```
ssh localhost
```

alternatively:

```
netstat -an | grep -w LISTEN | grep -w 22
```

If not installed, have a look to https://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections

Comment: I updated my question, both give "bad" results.

Comment: You are confusing ssh clients and servers. You need to install the ssh client package on the guest.

Comment: I had done that, but it wasn't enough. I installed ssh server and everything is fine now.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously meant install the **server** packages on the guest.

Comment: I know. :) You might want to update your answer with this super relevant question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections

Answer (score 2):

Check List:

1. Are you able to Ping Slave-1 ?
2. Slave-1 IPtables have allowed SSH port ? Stop IPTables and try once.

   ```
    service iptables stop
   ```
3. Slave-1 is having SSH service running or not ? If yes try restarting once.

   ```
   service sshd start

   service sshd stop

   service sshd restart
   ```
4. Make sure you didnt changed SSH default port.

Comment: I updated my question just when you posted, does this affect your answer?

Comment: @gsamaras Follow my checklist and let me know if still you are facing issue and update shows ssh service may be not running in your Slave-1

Comment: I pinged slave-1 from the master successfully. I do not know to do the rest of the steps. :/

Comment: @gsamaras updated

Comment: @gsamaras yes in Slave-1

Comment: I am getting `iptables: unrecognized service` and `sshd: unrecognized service`.

Comment: ok I thought you are using centos , for Ubuntu just try with service ssh start

Comment: I am getting `ssh: unrecognized service`! But I can do `ssh master` without a problem. :/

Comment: have you installed ssh in Slave-1 ?

Comment: `openssh-client is already the newest version.`, but still I think no.